# Finding the name of the object that a specific value belongs to

Tags: java

I am creating a bank application in Java but I am having some troubles with the way that the accounts are created/work.

I have created quite a lot of back-end for my application and am now working on the front-end using JavaFX. The issue I am having is with my login screen and how I can see if the username entered matches up with the password that the user has given on signup.

All usernames are currently stored in a `String[]` called 'usernames' and this is what I am using to check if the username exists.

How do I match a password up with the username value and see if it is the same as what the user entered?

```
for (int i = 0; i < usernamesCurrent.length; i++) {
    if (usernamesCurrent[i] == usernameText.getText() && /*THIS IS WHAT I AM HAVING PROBLEMS WITH*/) {

    }
}
```

Comment: *All usernames are currently stored in a String[] called 'usernames'*. Yikes!!!. *usernamesCurrent[i] == usernameText.getText()* Double Yikes!! Don't use `String` to store passwords. Use `char[] arrays`. Also `==` checks for identity. To check for equality, use `equals`.

Comment: You must use .equals to compare objects, including Strings

Comment: @ChetanKinger care to elaborate on your "yikes" moments' meanings?

Comment: Also, I currently don't have any way to test for the passwords as I don't know how they are linked together with the usernames.

Comment: @Glazy Sorry about that. Didn't mean to be rude. My comment already explains why both ideas are not recommended/don't work. You can search the site for more details.

Comment: Use a `Map` to store the credentials instead of String[]

Comment: @ChetanKinger Ahh right thank you, I see now! I just seen the "yikes" and thought to ask you what I done so wrong. I understand using the .equals() method and this is something I would've most likely picked up on when it came to running my code.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan Thank you! I will have a look into Maps and what they are all about.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall approach is questionable. But for this particular problem use .equals() method instead of == operator.

Use like - `if (usernamesCurrent[i].equals(usernameText.getText()) && ------`

Comment: Thanks for your response but this isn't what I was needing help with. I want to find a way to link the username and password together so that I can find out if that password belongs to the same object that the username does.